# Reinstalling a belt on an electric snow thrower

Tags: tools, winter

I have this [snow thrower](http://www.wenproducts.com/store/snow-throwers/WEN-13-A-18-inch-Electric-Snow-Thrower-Item-5662) which was doing pretty good for me until this weekend when it suddenly stopped turning the augers. I could hear the electric motor turning, but the augers where not turning. So I opened it up and found (along with a *lot* of ice build up) that the belt had come off. Trouble is, I'm not sure how to get the belt back on.

Here's a picture:

[image]

Now the belt obviously has to connect part A to part C, but I'm not sure how part B plays into this? It's spring loaded and can be pushed up, so I'm guessing it's supposed to tension the belt? And the belt should pass under it? Any tips on how to get the belt back on because I'm have trouble stretching it from A to C. I briefly had it on, but it just flew straight back off again when I tried to run it.

Comment: Is the auger free moving without the belt on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the way the spring is oriented on the idler pulley B, my guess is that it's meant to pull downward on the belt when it's installed, so the belt probably goes like this:

[image]

The exploded parts diagram in the owner manual (on the page you linked to)  shows the belt in this same orientation:

[image]

There might be a slot or hole in the idler pulley assembly that would let you pry it back with a screwdriver or other tool while you slip the belt on the main pulleys.

When the machine jammed with ice, the auger may have stopped and the belt may have been damaged if the motor was still spinning. Look for signs of cracks, worn down spots, etc both on the belt and the pulleys. If you can't find an exact replacement belt (part number *PJ670 - 56663-024* on the parts diagram), a small engine repair shop may be able to find an equivalent replacement.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me from that photo which way the belt is supposed to go, but the tensioner pulley should be positioned so that the spring creates tension in the belt. If the belt is a V belt (meaning the inside edge is thinner than the outside edge) you can also use that to tell which way the pulley should go.

If you got the belt on once and it comes off, it's possible the belt itself is damaged (check for cracks or missing chunks) or one of the pulleys is damaged (check for bends) or clogged with ice.